# MVC security role check in the ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Is it good security practice putting a security related property in the ViewModel, for use in a View, i.e. showing/hiding "stuff" depending on the user's role?

For example:

ViewModel property AdminRole. Setting it's value in the Controller (User.IsInRole), then in the View accessing the property: if (Model.AdminRole) { show admin stuff... }

I've read other SO posts and (some) people are doing it this way, but questioning if this is safe, i.e. exposing a security property in the ViewModel. If there is a better, more secure way please let me know.

Off topic, but related: IMHO this is far better than calling User.IsInRole in the View directly.

Comment: Are you concern that it is "not safe" because anyone with access to the `ViewModel` would be able to control the value of `AdminRole`?

Comment: Concerned when the ViewModel gets hijacked from a http request somehow (if this is even possible), and they set the AdminRole property to true, thereby bypassing the IsInRole authentication.

Comment: If your ViewModel is being passed into your action  method and variable assignment is done by model binding then, yes, it could get hijacked using the Mass Assignment Vulnerability (http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). If this is a concern, the I would use any of the other approaches to get data into your view.

Comment: I am using a viewmodel which is passed to an action method, and therefore uses the default model binding, and would be vunerable to Mass Assignment Vulnerability. Thank you, wasn't aware of this. This answers my question. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ViewModel is being passed into your action method and variable assignment is done by model binding then, yes, it could get hijacked using the [Mass Assignment Vulnerability](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). If this is a concern, the I would use any of the other approaches to get data into your view.

Comment: It is not a problem if the security is passed from the controller to the view. Inside the view, you can compare and display stuff you want. The problem only reside if you send back to from the view to the controller back. This should not be bound bidirectionally. Using a ViewModel having a property like IsAdmin is totally secure if done correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If by "ViewModel" you are referring to DTOs used for MVC views (as opposed to the ViewModel in an MVVM framework) then no, this is not a good design.

First of all, it's a bad design from a security perspective because:

1. You are relying on your **view** to actually **enforce** the security rules (e.g. by checking `AdminRole` to conditionally render content). This is difficult to test or review effectively.
2. You run the risk of unintentionally leaking private security information to the client, due to bugs or just sloppy coding.
3. You run the risk of accidentally having this property used in `POST`, `PUT`, or other "write" action without proper sanitization.

But more importantly, it's simply bad design from an MVC perspective, as it's missing the point of what a View Model is supposed to be.

View Models are meant to contain information about how to *display a view*. They are supposed to **abstract** the business logic that would otherwise go in a view, not just *pass it on*.

A better design for this scenario is something like this:

**ViewModel**

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool CanDeleteItems { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdminMenuVisible { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new IndexViewModel
    {
        CanDeleteItems = User.IsInRole("ContentManager"),
        IsAdminMenuVisible = User.IsInRole("Administrator"),
        // Other properties...
    });
}
```

**View**

```
@if (Model.IsAdminMenuVisible)
{
    <!-- Markup for admin menu -->
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <!-- Markup for item -->
    <button type="submit"  @((Model.CanDeleteItems) ? "disabled" : "")>Delete</button>
}
```

The idea here is that the ViewModel contains only properties that are **specific to the view itself**. The view doesn't get to decide under what *business conditions* a certain element is visible, disabled, etc. The view model will tell it *exactly* what to display and when, using properties named after the specific view elements that they are bound to.

This is better for maintainability as well. What happens if you decide that users should be able to delete items if they have the "ContentManager" OR the "Administrator" role? In your version, you'd end up modifying the view; in the above version, you'd only need to modify the controller. If you find yourself having to modify views for reasons other than changing the look and feel, it means you've made a mistake in your architecture. Security checks should happen in the controller.

---

Note, depending on your architectural style it may also be acceptable for you to implement these as derived properties in your ViewModel, for example:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    private readonly IPrincipal user;

    public IndexViewModel(IPrincipal user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public bool CanDeleteItems
    {
        get { return user.IsInRole("ContentManager"); }
    }

    public bool IsAdminMenuVisible
    {
        get { return user.IsInRole("Administrator"); }
    }
}
```

This is a somewhat more object-oriented design and is equally acceptable because the view model doesn't actually expose the underlying rules to the view, and is just as testable as a controller. Like I said above, it's more of a matter of personal preference, and whether you want your ViewModels to be intelligent (as in MVVM) or just dumb DTOs (more MVC style).

Comment: Yes - DTOs. Great points regarding bad design. All true! Each security related property, e.g. CanDeleteItems, state what the property will be used for, resulting in better razor code. And the view model only contains properties specific for the view rather than a very generic IsAdmin property. And as you said, this result in an improved maintenance aspect, This is a great answer in regards to design! 10/10! I would select this as the answer, but Queti has answered the question in regards to making the code more secure. Thank you very much, this helps alot!

Comment: @Aaronaught good answer but your solution doesn't cover mass assignment when the viewmodel is passed back into an action method. If you have a dozen different roles you would have to do a lot of checks again in the controller before setting field for an update or create. How do you abstract this logic out of a controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of which approach you use, you will use the `User.IsInRole` to determine if you should show/hide "stuff".

In addition to the two approaches you described (setting a ViewModel property or using the User.IsInRole in the view directly), the only other ways I can think of passing a value is to use a ViewBag, ViewData, Session, Cookie..... all these methods pretty much work the same.

**How I do it:**

At the beginning of my view I use `User.IsInRole` and then save the value into a local property that I then check further down in the page to show/hide stuff.

Comment: From the comments above... since you're logic is in the View, you are avoiding Mass Assignment Vulnerability. But is there any way to circumvent your local property in the view, i.e. set this value for malicious purposes? (I don't see how as the logic and property are executed on the server side).

Comment: No, no one would be able to set the value of the local property in any way. Just note that when you show/hide "stuff", make sure you are preventing the rendering of the HTML, not just setting a CSS class/style to "hide" the HTML. You want to make sure the hidden html does not reach the client.

Comment: Just as I thought (and hoped). Was confirming. Thanks.